# FCM notifications not working after changing the package name

Tags: php, android, push-notification, package, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send the notifications. It was working perfect till I changed the package name.

As I changed package name, I created new project in firebase console, got the new key and sending notification with new key from php, but I am not getting the notifications. As I test from firebase its working.

As I tried to debug I found that onMessageReceived is not getting called though is in foreground.

MessageService:

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private String mUserId;
    private Boolean mUpdateNotification;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        String clickAction = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

        mUserId = remoteMessage.getData().get("user_id");

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),clickAction,title);
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody,String clickAction,String title) {

        mUpdateNotification = true;

        Intent intent = new Intent(clickAction);

        intent.putExtra("userId",mUserId);
        intent.putExtra("updateNotification",mUpdateNotification);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.contacts_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

PHP :

```
 public function sendPush($text, $tokens, $apiKey)
{

    $notification = array(
        "title" => "You got an invitation.",
        "text" => $text,
        "click_action" => "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"

    );

    $msg = array
    (
        'message' => $text,
        'title' => 'You got an invitation.',
    );
    $fields = array
    (
        'to' => $tokens,
        'data' => $msg,
        'notification' => $notification
    );

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //  echo($result);
    //    return $result;
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.weberz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/contacts_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" />

        <service android:name=".helper.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".helper.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"
                    android:enabled="true"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.DetailViewActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ProfileActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.StartUpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".helper.MessageService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.InviteContactsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.PendingInvitesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pending_invites"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".helper.MessageService$SmsSentReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".helper.MessageService$SmsDeliveredReceiver" />

        <activity android:name=".Activities.PreferencesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.weberz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anyone tell what's gong wrong please?? Thank you..

Comment: post your complete gradle and manifest?

Comment: Can u double check is package name in Firebase console and gradle and manifest are same.?

Comment: yes checked many times.. As it works from firebase then it should not be a problem..  Added manifest and gradle .. :-( @Raghavendra

Comment: May be a dumb question.. In your old implementation the manifest statement was same? I meant <service android:name=".helper.MyFirebaseMessagingService"> ?

Comment: yes was same. Which api key I need to use in server? Web api key from firebase console or as I generated new json file then it's showing current_key in api_key as I checked both seems different. Which key should be used? @Raghavendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json (google-service.json) file needs to be re-extracted for keeping it in your app folder

To get your Web API Key...

```
1. Go to Firebase Console
2. Select Your Project … then click on the gear icon next to project name and click on Project settings then move on to CLOUD MESSAGING tab.
```

Comment: yes I added new json file in app folder. @Nougat Lover

Comment: Can you open and reconfirm your package_name in .json file?

Comment: "package_name": "com.weberz" this is the package name in json file. @Nougat Lover

Comment: Which api key I need to use in server? Web api key from firebase console or as I generated new json file then it's showing current_key in api_key as I checked both seems different. Which key should be used? @Nougat Lover

Comment: Your client key and server key will be different.

Comment: I am using php, how to add in that? It seems web api key needs to be added in server, I too used web api key in php script. @Nougat Lover

Comment: Authorization: key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY  Check this is correct or not

Comment: Glad it helped you :-)